# How to combine multiple rows into one with nulled values where row values differ

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I do with SQL Server to get a single row where the only non-null values are the ones that are consistent and non-null through all the selected rows.

```
 A    B     C     D
10   NULL  text  NULL
4    abc   text  NULL
4    def   text  NULL
```

Should give the following row:

```
 A    B     C     D
NULL NULL  text  NULL
```

Comment: It's a query used in a form when editing multiple rows: The only fields filled with a value are the ones having the same values across the whole selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @t table(A int, b varchar(10), c varchar(max), d int)

insert @t values(10, null, 'text', null)
insert @t values(4, 'abc', 'text', null)
insert @t values(10, 'def', 'text', null)


select case when max(rna) > 1 then null else min(a) end, 
case when max(rnb) > 1 then null else min(b) end, 
case when max(rnc) > 1 then null else min(c) end, 
case when max(rnd) > 1 then null else min(d) end 
 from 
(
select rna = rank() over(order by a),
rnb = rank() over(order by b),
rnc = rank() over(order by c),
rnd = rank() over(order by d),
a, b,c,d
 from @t
 ) e
```

If you have text columns replace the column type with varchar(max). Text columns are outdated.

Using count(distinct col1) was by first thought, but it doesn't count null values.

```
select count(distinct a) from (select cast(null as int) a) b
```

returns 0 rows

Answer (score 4):

```
create table #t (col1 int, col2 char(3), col3 char(4), col4 int)
go
insert into #t select 10, null, 'text', null
insert into #t select 4, 'abc', 'text', null
insert into #t select 4, 'def', 'text', null
go

select 
    case when count(distinct isnull(col1, 0)) > 1 then null else max(col1) end as 'col1',
    case when count(distinct isnull(col2, '')) > 1 then null else max(col2) end as 'col2',
    case when count(distinct isnull(col3, '')) > 1 then null else max(col3) end as 'col3',
    case when count(distinct isnull(col4, 0)) > 1 then null else max(col4) end as 'col4'
from 
    #t
go

drop table #t
go
```

**EDIT**: I added ISNULL to handle the issue identified by t-clausen.dk but this will only work if the 'default' values (i.e. zero and empty string) do not appear in the real data.

Daniel's comment about data types is also correct, but since we don't know the data types involved it's not easy to suggest an alternative. Providing a self-contained test script that uses the real data types is the best way to ask questions like this.

Comment: I was considering a solution like this. Problem is that "null" is not being counted. If you remove the last insert, you will see what i mean

Comment: count() doesn't work for all types. For instance, it doesn't work with ntext columns.

Comment: @Daniel - text, ntext and image are all deprecated and should not be used.  Use VARCHAR(max) NVARCHAR(max) and VARBINARY(max) instead.  Do you actually have any columns that are the deprecated types?

Comment: I also considered using isnull or coalesce. Again problem. What if one of the replacement values already exists ? It is possible to use a strange random value like "#%&(//&()" and a very low negative number, but you are risking mistakes. a = 0, a = 0, a = null would accept 0 as answer.

Comment: @Dems - I was using ntext, but now I know they are deprecated, I will replace them with nvarchar(max).

Comment: @t-clausen.dk As I mentioned in my edit, default values for ISNULL() must not appear in the real data; if there are no possible defaults then obviously a different solution is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN  COUNT(DISTINCT col1) = 1
           AND COUNT(col1) = COUNT(*) 
         THEN MIN(col1)
    END AS col1
  , CASE WHEN  COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 1 
           AND COUNT(col2) = COUNT(*)
         THEN MIN(col2)
    END AS col2
  , CASE WHEN  COUNT(DISTINCT col3) = 1 
           AND COUNT(col3) = COUNT(*)
         THEN MIN(col3)
    END AS col3
  , CASE WHEN  COUNT(DISTINCT col4) = 1 
           AND COUNT(col4) = COUNT(*)
         THEN MIN(col4)
    END AS col4
FROM
    tableX
```

Comment: +1 really nice and simple, better than my solution, I imagine it will perform faster.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Thnx. `COUNT(DISTINCT column) = 1` could also be replaced with `MIN(column)=MAX(column)`